# Scrapy: How to output items in a specific json format

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I output the scraped data in json format.
Default scrapy exporter outputs list of dict in json format.
Item type looks like:

```
[{"Product Name":"Product1", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"20.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product2", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"21.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product3", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"22.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product4", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"23.5", "Currency":"USD"}, ...]
```

But I want to export the data in a specific format like this:

```
{
"Shop Name":"Shop 1",
"Location":"XXXXXXXXX",
"Contact":"XXXX-XXXXX",
"Products":
[{"Product Name":"Product1", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"20.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product2", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"21.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product3", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"22.5", "Currency":"USD"},
{"Product Name":"Product4", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"23.5", "Currency":"USD"}, ...]
}
```

Please advice me any solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Where did you expect to get `Shop Name`, `Location`... from? are you going to manually define them every time?

Comment: No, I receive it as parameter when the spider start running.

Comment: Then can you show us some more information on how to parameters are received and defined? Some of your code would help.

Comment: I did not implement it yet. I gonna read csv file stores parameter list.

Comment: so `{"Product Name":"Product1", "Categories":["Clothing","Top"], "Price":"20.5", "Currency":"USD"}` would be an scrapy item right? and you want to include `Shop Name, Location, etc.`  in the final file?

Comment: You are right. !

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273447/change-scrapy-json-output?rq=1) is solution. How do you think?

Comment: @bbanzzakji yeah, that should be it

Comment: Anyway thank you for your interesting.

Answer (score 7):

This is well documented at scrapy web page [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.JsonLinesItemExporter).

```
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter


class ItemPipeline(object):

    file = None

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('item.json', 'w')
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

This will create a json file containing your items.

Comment: all i want to do is prettify the `json` file that was spit out from a python script. will this work?!

Comment: @Anthony As you can see in [JsonItemExporter docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#jsonitemexporter) this class accept a `kwargs` parameter. I read source code on github for a while and found a [`self.indent`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/exporters.py#L105) attribute in this class. So you need JsonItemExporter(self.file, indent=2) to get a pretty format Json (as I understand, this is not tested). Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: This worked for me after some adjustments 
**(1)** activate generated setting ITEM_PIPELINES
**(2)** Opening file as binary, to avoid 
`builtins.TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` 
**(3-optional)** naming output file after the spider: 

`self.file = open(spider.name + '.json', 'wb')`

Comment: @Gocht `JsonItemExporter(self.file, indent=2)` then works beautifully !

Comment: why is file = None

Comment: `self.file = open('item.json', 'w')` needs to be allowed to write bytes: `self.file = open('item.json', 'wb')`

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to export pretty printed JSON and this is what worked for me.

I created a pipeline that looked like this:

```
class JsonPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('your_file_name.json', 'wb')
        self.file.write("[")

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.write("]")
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(
            dict(item),
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=4,
            separators=(',', ': ')
        ) + ",\n"

        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

It's similar to the example from the scrapy docs https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html except it prints each JSON property indented and on a new line.

See the part about pretty printing here https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: What is `your_file_name.json`?

Comment: @Max This add/print an extra `,` at the end of the file. It is not a valid json file.

Comment: why the `wb` mode? doesn't that mean `write` and `binary`??

Answer (score 0):

There is also one more possible solution to generate spider outputs in a json directly from the spider directly from the command line.

```
scrapy crawl "name_of_your_spider" -a NAME_OF_ANY_ARGUMENT=VALUE_OF_THE_ARGUMENT -o output_data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to take a json export of the scraped/crawled output from a scrapy spider is to enable feed export which is one of the inherent, inbuilt capabilities that are offered in the scrapy classes which could be enabled or disabled as per the requirements. One can go about doing this by defining the custom_settings (overriding) of the spider in the following manner. This ends up overriding the overall scrapy project settings for this specific spider.

So, for any spider named 'sample_spider':

```
class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sample_spider"
    allowed_domains = []

    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'sample_spider_crawled_data.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_EXPORTERS': {
            'json': 'scrapy.exporters.JsonItemExporter',
        },
        'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
    }
```